# What is the set builder notation definition of a bijective function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is there a set builder notation for bijective function?

If so what is it?

But before, is the definition below for injective function or bijective function? :

$$[y|∀y ∈ B, ∃!x ∈ A: y=f(x)] $$

(**B=f(A)**)

Comment: but why my definition is wrong though?

Comment: It is not wrong, but I wrote in full detail, whereas you used an abbreviation for the existence of a unique element. Let me rewrite it in a better way $(\forall y \in Y \exists x \in X\ y = f(x)) \land (\forall x_1,x_2 \in X \ f(x_1) = f(x_2) \to x_1 = x_2)$. So now it read surjective and bijective

Comment: Aha thanks a lot now it makes sense

Comment: It may be a good thing to recall that one cannot $say$ using set builder notation that a function is bijective, because set builder notation denotes an *object* ( namely a set) , but does not express a *sentence* such that " $f$ is bijective".